# Personalize my-weather-indicator notify-send messages

Tags: notify-send, my-weather-indicator

I'm quite satisfied with the my-weather-indicator widget, it also provides frequent notifications through notify-send on Ubuntu. Would it be possible to alter and personalize the notification message it sends?

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your local installed version...

Assuming you have the indicator installed in the default location `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator`, edit `share/my-weather-indicator/myweatherindicator.py` and look for calls involving the variables `self.notification` and `self.notification2` and customise the text as desired.